# Labels for terms in the lambda calculus

Tags: lo.logic, terminology, lambda-calculus

In the lambda calculus, are there commonly accepted names for $x$ and $M$ when they appear in $\lambda x [M]$  ? Something along the lines of "binder" and "bindee"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$x$ is a "bound variable" and $M$ is the "scope" in which it is bound.

Comment: I would say that the scope of $x$ is the whole expression $\lambda x.M$.

Comment: @Emil Jeřábek Since $x$ can only be evaluated in $M$, I'm not sure what adding the lambda adds to the notion of scope.  But hey, if that is how you like it... ;-)

Comment: Personally I couldn’t care less. However, the question is not how I like it, but what is the commonly accepted terminology, and I believe it is what I wrote above.

Comment: I agree with Marc here. The scope is the body $M$. BTW, expressions like "I couldn't care less" come across as very rude, though I'm sure that's not your intention.

Comment: I apologize, I didn’t intend to be rude.

Answer (score 1):

In logic the $\phi$ in $\forall x . \phi$ is called *the matrix*, and $x$ the *bound variable* and $\forall x$ the *quantifier*. By this analogy I would call $M$ in $\lambda x . M$ the matrix, $x$ is the bound variable, and $\lambda x$ is the abstraction, or maybe the "abstractor"?